# Mamp and RewriteBase

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

I use Mamp free version. I want to work local. For instance, make links work inside htdocs/site1 as they were in the root. To test I tried this:

Inside htdocs I have 2 folders: site1 and site2
Inside site1 I have 2 files: file1.php and file2.php
Inside site1 I have .htaccess with this:

```
RewriteBase /site1/
```

Inside file 1 I have a link to check if I can use absolute link. It does not work:

```
<a href="/file2.php" >go to file 2</a>
```

Is RewriteBase a good way to make links work in local?. How to do that?

Comment: where you place .htaccess ? at site1 directory ?

Comment: Yes, .htaccess is inside site1

Comment: so you what you need exactly , say it like that when press the link what you expected site1/file2.php or what ?

Comment: I try to make links work in local. So, I put an absolute link in file1.php and I want it to go to file2.php. Remember file2.php is inside htdocs/site1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> make links work inside htdocs/site1 as they were in the root

You will just need this single rule in `htdocs/.htaccess` (a level above `site1`)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!site1/).*)$ site1/$1 [NC,L]
```

You don't need `.htaccess inside`site1`for this, you can remove that`RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Yours is a  good solution to work local. I tried and it works. On the other side, do you know why my solution with RewriteBase /site1/ does not work? Perhaps I do not understand well RewriteBase ?

Comment: RewriteBase is only used for RewriteRule directives, it won't affect your URLs on its own.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. The question is, why this link does not work: <a href="/file2.php" >go to file 2</a> if there is the RewriteBase /site1/

Comment: Please pay attention to comment I wrote. RewriteBase doesn't affect href links. I cannot paste lot of text in comment section so my sincere advise is to read apache documentation on RewriteBase.